# What is the difference between a View and a View Controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

from an iphone development perspective

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A *view* is an object that is drawn to the screen. It may also contain other views (subviews) that are inside it and move with it. Views can get touch events and tell listeners or delegates about any events that occur in them. Views are dumb, and do not know about the structure of your application, and are simply told to display themselves in some state, and listened to for events.

For example: a text label, a button, a checkbox, a progress bar.

---

A *view controller* is not drawable to the screen directly, it manages a group of view objects.  View controllers usually have a single `view` with many subviews.  The view controller manages the state of these views.  A view controller is smart, and it knows how to interact with your application.  It tells the dumb view objects what to do and how to show themselves.

For example: a screen that shows a list of users, an edit user form, a login screen.

---

A view controller is the glue between your overall application and the screen.  It *controls* the views that it owns according to the logic of your application.

Comment: Your smart/dumb comparison made all the difference in my understanding. Thanks.

Comment: If you want a large hierarchy of views that include complex things like tables, you end up pretty much having to use UIViewControllers everywhere in iOS dev, right? And view controllers are tightly coupled with their views anyway. Seems to me like they should be one and the same to make things homogeneous.

Comment: "Can change their visual state in response" - reacting to such events and causing the view to change appearance is already in the realm of a view controller when views are truly dumb.

Answer (score 4):

The controller connects views (UI elements) to model objects. Views are for display, model objects are for data, controllers are the glue in between them.

See the [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1) for an explanation of the three tier architecture of the Model-View-Controller pattern.

Comment: Then why `UILabel` is a view, not a controller? We can consider the text (`String`) it displays to be a model, don't we? Then `UILabel` would be a blue between model (`String`) and view.

Answer (score 3):

I just got started with my first apps. Very simply put view is the visual aspect of the app

and view controller is the code that actually controls or manipulates the visual aspect.