# What's the difference between a View and a ViewController?

Tags: swift

Coming to Swift from Delphi, I thought the View represented an app's GUI and the storyboard was a visual representation of the View's underlying code. The ViewController was the one and only object the View interacted with. When a [popular tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81879/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-1) says

> In the old days developers used to create a separate interface file
>   for the design of each view controller.

I'm thinking the "separate interface file" was the View file. But as I learn more, I'm getting confused. Beneath a screenshot of an empty Main.storyboard from a new application, the text says

> The official storyboard terminology for a view controller is "scene,"
>   but you can use the terms interchangeably. The scene is what
>   represents a view controller in the storyboard ... Here you see a
>   single view controller containing an empty view.

So I'm seeing a "single view controller," not a view?? Confusion mounts when I note any views(?) displayed on a storyboard are called "View Controllers" in Swift.

So, what's the difference between a View and ViewController? How is a storyboard related? And what object "owns" something like a segue, which exists outside my (flawed) understanding of these concepts?

Comment: I can't answer that question as good as other people may do, so I will only comment here. The easiest way to tell the deference, is to think about the view controller as a container with one view, which will have other subviews. The view container will have some shiny callbacks you probably will need in some point of your application `func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)` or `func viewDidLayoutSubviews()` for example. The view itself is where you can draw something or create a view hierarchy as in the view controller except you won't have all the callbacks the view controller has.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Take a look at this post - [What is the difference between a View and a View Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632196/what-is-the-difference-between-a-view-and-a-view-controller)

This described it pretty well for me.

If you don't want to go to the link, here is a great description of the difference between a `view` and a `view controller` by [Alex Wayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62076/alex-wayne):

> A view is an object that is drawn to the screen. It may also contain
>   other views (subviews) that are inside it and move with it. Views can
>   get touch events and change their visual state in response. Views are
>   dumb, and do not know about the structure of your application, and are
>   simply told to display themselves in some state.
>
> A view controller is not drawable to the screen directly, it manages a
>   group of view objects. View controllers usually have a single view
>   with many subviews. The view controller manages the state of these
>   views. A view controller is smart, and has knowledge of your
>   application's inner workings. It tells the dumb view objects what to
>   do and how to show themselves.
>
> A view controller is the glue between your overall application and the
>   screen. It controls the views that it owns according to the logic of
>   your application.